# Is there a way to select the opposite of a custom type in Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, types

Is there a way to select the opposite of a custom defined type in a variable, using Typescript?

When I define a type like so:
`type Result = 'table' | 'grid';`
Then any variable with the type Result can have either 'table' or 'grid'.

Is there a way to get the opposite of 'table', i.e. 'grid'? In the same way that it can be done with booleans, like:

```
let a = false;
// a is false
a = !a;
// a is true
```

Not the exact syntax, by using the '!' operator, but the same idea of getting the opposite of a certain custom type?

Answer (score 1):

You can have its type like this:

```
type Result = 'table' | 'grid';
let table: Result = 'table';

let other: Exclude<Result, typeof table> = 'grid';
```

Here the type of `other` will be `grid`, you can't assign anything else to it.

I don't think you can assign it to a variable, types don't exist at runtime.